# How do I import a library into a SvelteKit app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit, cornerstonejs

I am trying to use the [Cornerstone3D library](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D/) in a SvelteKit app, but I am having trouble importing the library.

Here is a small example that reproduces my problem:

```bash
npm create svelte@latest my-app # install new SvelteKit app, skeleton, with typescript
cd my-app
npm install
npm install @cornerstonejs/core # install the library I want to work with
```

I add this script to the top of `src/routes/+page.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { utilities } from "@cornerstonejs/core"; // import a component of the library
</script>
```

When I test the site using `npm run dev`, I get the error

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my-app/node_modules/@cornerstonejs/core/dist/umd/index.js:2:9594)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1246:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1300:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:168:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25
```

which refers to a compiled JavaScript file.

I have tried modifying parts of `tsconfig.json`, such as `module` and `target` in the `compilerOptions`, but they have resulted in other errors like:

```
`Object.defineproperty(exports, "__esmodule", { value: true }); exports is not defined`
```

I have even tried loading the library in a JavaScript file and importing it into an HTML file (ex. `<script src="test.js"></script>`) without a framework, but I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've looked at other SvelteKit projects, and they seem to import libraries the same way, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but for that last error, you're incorrectly loading a module; to load a module using script tags, you need to specify that it's a module with the `type` attribute: `<script type="module" src="test.js"></script>`

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I'm not sure how to use this to import the library. Using `import { utilities } from "@cornerstonejs/core";` in `test.js` did not work. I changed it to `import { utilities } from "./node_modules/@cornerstonejs/core";` to match the file structure, but got the error `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: That's a separate an sveltekit specific issue, how it uses paths or serves content isn't something standardized like `<script type="module">` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library is not compatible with server-side rendering, you could  [turn it off](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) on pages that use it.

```js
// +page.ts
export const ssr = false
```

Comment: Hmm, I created a new app and made a new file `src/routes/+page.ts` containing:

```
import { utilities } from '@cornerstonejs/core';
export const ssr = false;
```

but I got the same error:

```
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/routes/+page.ts: failed to import "@cornerstonejs/core"
|- ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my-app/node_modules/@cornerstonejs/core/dist/umd/index.js:2:9594)
```

I'm not sure why it still says `SSR module`.

Comment: The import should ***not*** be in the `+page.ts` file. Also, `+page.ts` only applies to one route. If you want to affect multiple routes, use a layout, see the linked documentation.

Comment: Ah okay, I was able to get past that error, thanks! How did you know that the problem was with server-side rendering? Was it from the error message or in the documentation somewhere? Also, what JavaScript should go into `+page.ts` vs. `+page.svelte`? I couldn't figure that out from the documentation.

Comment: SSR errors are just the most common issue. `+page.svelte` is just the page component, `+page.ts` is for [options](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options) and [loading data](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load), though other features might be added in the future. The [routing docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) give an overview of the various files.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much for your help and for responding so quickly.